# Code License that allows for Redistribution but No Compiling then Redistributing

Tags: perl, licensing

Essentially, I have an interesting Perl script that I want to put on Github / other places that I want to be re-distributable but I do not want anyone compiling it and then redistributing it (yes I know the source would be included with certain licenses - but I don't want it to ever be compiled at all).

Those who can figure out how to use CPAN, etc, to set it up - I want them to be able to use it and redistribute it in source format but is there a way of restricting the compilation and then redistribution. I only want to allow users to redistribute in source.

Comment: what do you mean by "compiling"?

Comment: also, why do you want to do this?  some insight into your reasons might help someone come up with a solution that fits

Comment: No matter what license you use, if people want to redistribute it in some other way, they will. The real question is whether you care enough to hire lawyers and have a protracted legal fight over it, especially when the bad things happen in some country very far away.

Comment: @brian d foy Yes, but a license lets people who are acting in good faith know how you want your code treated.

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements are at odds with each other.  The first step of running a Perl 5 program is compiling.  Your best bet is the [GPLv3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPLv3#Version_3), it requires anyone who distributes a compiled version to also provide a method to retrieve the source.

Most of the methods of making a binary out of a Perl 5 script (which I think you are confusing with compiling) aren't actually compiling.  They are packaging.  The source is still present in the binary and is compiled at run-time by an included copy of the `perl` binary.